# Kafka Streams - The method of(Duration) from the type JoinWindows is deprecated

Tags: java, join, apache-kafka, time, apache-kafka-streams

I want to join a KStream<String, String> with a KTable<Windowed, int[]> to obtain results from the last hour, using JoinWindows.of(Duration).

My code is as follows:

```
Duration windowSize = Duration.ofMinutes(60);
Duration advanceSize = Duration.ofMinutes(1);
TimeWindows hoppingWindow = TimeWindows.ofSizeWithNoGrace(windowSize).advanceBy(advanceSize);
Duration joinWindowSizeMs = Duration.ofHours(1);

// Aggregate to get [sum, count] in the last time window
KTable<Windowed<String>, int[]> averageTemp = mainStreamStandard.groupByKey()
.windowedBy(hoppingWindow)
.aggregate( () -> new int[]{0 ,0}, (aggKey, newVal, aggValue) -> {
        aggValue[0] += Integer.valueOf(newVal.split(":")[1]);
        aggValue[1] += 1;  
        return aggValue;
        }, Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new IntArraySerde()));
        
// Join weather stations with their [sum,count] and their respective red alert events
KStream<String, String> joined = mainStreamAlert.join(averageTemp,
JoinWindows.of(joinWindowSizeMs),
(leftValue, rightValue) -> "left/" + leftValue + "/right/" + rightValue[0]/rightValue[1]);
```

It gives an error saying "The method of(Duration) from the type JoinWindows is deprecated". It also tells me to change the "join" method to "leftJoin" but it doesn't change anything.

What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`of(Duration timeDifference)` is indeed deprecated.

The direct replacement for this method is `ofTimeDifferenceAndGrace(Duration timeDifference, Duration afterWindowEnd)`.

The deprecated method had a default grace period of 24 hours. So your code would look like this:

```
...
Duration joinWindowSizeMs = Duration.ofHours(1);
Duration gracePeriod = Duration.ofHours(24);
...
// Join weather stations with their [sum,count] and their respective red alert events
KStream<String, String> joined = mainStreamAlert.join(averageTemp,
JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceAndGrace(joinWindowSizeMs, gracePeriod),
(leftValue, rightValue) -> "left/" + leftValue + "/right/" + rightValue[0]/rightValue[1]);
```

[JoinWindows documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/JoinWindows.html#ofTimeDifferenceAndGrace(java.time.Duration,java.time.Duration))